# Internal links listed as backlinks

Tags: google-search

The search phrase in google `link:www.sitename.com` will list all the back links for the specified web site. When many of the sites www.sitename.com/xxx is also listed as backlinks. Our website has thousands of pages indexed in google and has a good interlinking. However I do not see these links listed as backlinks by google? What is the missing piece here?

Answer (score 0):

The link command does not list all backlinks and internal links are not considered as backlinks. Your assumption is wrong.